# Enforce Range on Support Vector Regression Predictions

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, svr

I am using sklearn's Support Vector Regression to predict the flow of a pipe. The flow is continuous, and within a range say (-2000, 2000). Is there a way to engineer such information such that the model will never (or at least heavily discouraged) to make a out-of-range prediction?

One idea I have is to turn this into a classification problem where the labels would be load factors of the pipe -1.0, -0.9, ..., 0.0, 0.1, ..., 1.0. However, I am unsure if this is worth the potential sacrifice in real-world accuracy.